# What does a range of 2..-1 mean? (Ruby koans about_arrays.rb)

Tags: ruby

Please could someone explain what a range object of `2..-1` means.

Ruby koans has the following in about_arrays.rb:

```
def test_slicing_with_ranges
  array = [:peanut, :butter, :and, :jelly]

  assert_equal [:peanut, :butter, :and], array[0..2]
  assert_equal [:peanut, :butter], array[0...2]
  assert_equal [:and, :jelly], array[2..-1]
end
```

The following website (found from another answer) explains how ranges work with slicing:
[Gary Wright, string/array slices](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1393096#990065)
From this, I understand why the split gives the answer it does. The thing I don't understand is WHAT range the range object is referring to. For a normal range, I can do:

```
(1..3).each { |x| puts(x) }
```

which gives the following output when executed in irb:

```
1
2
3
=> 1..3e
```

However, `(2..-1).each { |x| puts(x) }` gives:

```
=> 2..-1
```

So what does the range `(2..-1)` mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A negative index means "counting from the end of the array." So `-1` is the last item in the array. `2..-1` means from the third item to the last.

Comment: Thanks @DragoonWraith. Maybe I'm thinking about the range object incorrectly. From your answer, its a range with a start of 2 (third item) and an end of -1 (last item). I guess what's confusing me is what does this mean outside the context of splitting: what numbers are 'between' the 2 and -1; why doesn't `(2..-1).each` print anything?

Comment: @Will: You only have three items in your array, so there's nothing in between `2` and the last one; `2` *is* the last one. That's why you're not seeing anything. If you try with a larger array, you should see things.

Comment: "what numbers are 'between' the 2 and -1" – None. "why doesn't (2..-1).each print anything?" – That's why ;-)

Comment: @Will: A [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html) serves two distinct purposes: (1) a pair of end points (2) an Enumerable that ranges between the end points. So you can say `r = 1.1 .. 1.2` and work with the end points just fine but `r.each` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

array = [:peanut, :butter, :and, :jelly]

```
array[2..-1] => [:and, :jelly]
```

(2..-1) means starting from 2nd index to the last item of the array.

'..' is the inclusive range.